# Minio data transfer

Tags: minio

I have a broken minio cluster and don't have access to the control plane. I still have access to the filesystem directory with data and buckets, access to .minio-sys where the broken minio config and other cluster data are located. How can I migrate all my data/buckets with all the files in them to a new minio cluster?

Answer (score 0):

If you were running a single MinIO instance, this is simple - just copy the the directory containing `.minio.sys` onto another system and start MinIO again with the new directory.

If you were running multiple instances (i.e. distributed MinIO), copy each directory containing `.minio.sys` into new disks (each such directory is a "disk" for MinIO) and start MinIO on the new disks.